# How to enumerate and print out the variables in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, printing

Is there a way to enumerate all the variables in a bash script and print out their values?

If that is not possible is there a way to print out the value of avariable give its name, ie from a string like 'ABC' print the value of $ABC if it has been assigned?

Comment: All the variables directly used by a script or all the variables available in the shell session?

Comment: Those used in the script, but if those available in the shell session can also be listed that will also be good.

Comment: The latter is easier. The former is somewhat impossible. That being said there isn't a way to "inspect" a script for the variables it will use (or expects to have set before being run or anything like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `compgen -v` builtin:

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line=${!line}"; done < <(compgen -v)
```

Fore more details use:

```
help compgen
```

To list all variable created by your scripts (`.bashrc` etc):

```
{ set -o posix; set; }
```

Comment: Yes both snippets will work from inside the script also.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the output to only the variables in the script?

Comment: Did you try: `{ set -o posix; set; }` from your script?